# Calculation inaccuracy in date difference

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I tried to find the duration of the number of days of the starting date until the present time using `Sys.time()`. I use the following command to find the duration. However the output in R is totally wrong.

```
person$duration <-  lubridate::interval(as.Date(person$create_date, "%m/%d/%y"),Sys.Date()) %/% days()
```

The output:

```
Name          create_date       duration            
A             09/23/2014        -811       
B             05/05/2014        -670
```

It is supposed to be **1380 days** NOT -811. I am not sure why is it negative and why is it '-811' or '-670' specifically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the simple difference

```
as.numeric(as.Date("2018-07-05") - Sys.Date())
# use abs() if the date it's in the past
```

Comment: This sort of answers the question. `as.numeric(Sys.Date() - as.Date("09/23/2014", "%m/%d/%Y"))`.

Answer (score 4):

You were very close. Since your year consists of 4 digits, you need a capital Y.

```
library(lubridate)
interval(as.Date("09/23/2014", "%m/%d/%Y"),Sys.Date()) %/% days()
```

gives 1380.

In your code it took only the first 2 digits, and it assumed you wanted the current century, so year 2020. To be exact: in case you provide two numbers as a year, values between 69 and 99 are converted to 1969-1999, and values between 00 and 68 to 2000-2068.

```
interval(as.Date("09/23/2020", "%m/%d/%Y"),Sys.Date()) %/% days()
```

gives -811 as well.